# Не корректная работа ng-repeat (Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] )

Tags: php, json, angularjs, http

Имею следующий контроллер:

```
app.controller('comboController', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://InternetShop/php_files/supermarket.php?category=main").
    success(function (data) {
        $scope.categoryes = data;
        console.log($scope.categoryes);
    }); 
});

$scope.categoryes получает следующую дату - main["Meat","Fish","Buckery","Vodka"]
```

Но когда я хочу построить следующий код разметки

```
<div  class="form-group col-sm-2" ng-controller="comboController">
    <select  class="form-control">
        <optgroup ng-repeat="category in categoryes"> 
            <option ng-click="GetCategoryName(category)">{{category}}</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>
```

консоль бьет следующую ошибку:

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=category%20in%20categoryes&p1=string%3Aa&p2=a
at angular.min.js:6
at angular.min.js:300
at angular.min.js:141
at m.$digest (angular.min.js:142)
at m.$apply (angular.min.js:145)
at l (angular.min.js:97)
at D (angular.min.js:101)
at XMLHttpRequest.w.onload (angular.min.js:102)
```

Погуглив немного нашел вроде бы решение - изменил директиву `ng-repeat`, написал `ng-repeat="category in categoryes track by $index"`
Но после этого в моем выпадающем списке отображаются поочередно с каждой новой строки символы пришедшей в дате строки(он видит дату как строку)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: выведи в консоль: `console.log(typeof $scope.categoryes);` Судя по всему это строка, и вывод вполне соответствует входным данным. Если ты хотел получить массив, то у тебя некорректный ответ от сервера

Comment: спасибо за ответ, однако не могу понять почему сервер передает строку

Comment: убери `print_r($category);`. что происходит в `GetAllCategory()`?

Comment: function GetAllCategory(){
    $data = GetJSON();
    $categorys = new Category();
    $categorys->SetCategory($data);
    echo $categorys->EnCodeCategory();
}

Comment: создаю объект декодирую обратно в джейсон

Comment: тогда при убирании `print_r($category);` все должно заработать

Comment: Спасибо все зароботало